# How to start scroll from current position while using ScrollToAsync function in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a horizontal scrollview with series of images.When I use ScrollToAsync function scroll starts from start of the scrollview (Horizontal orientation) and then scrolls to desired element. What should I do to make the scrollview scroll from the current position instead of start position.

```
scroll.ScrollToAsync(stackLayout.Children[Index],ScrollToPosition.Start,true);
```

> Note: This happens only when ScrollOrientation is Horizontal

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior for iOS in Vertical ScrollOrientation. I'm using Xamarin Forms 2.2.0.45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of forms are you using, this bug seems to fixed in 1.5.1-pre1

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28965